# How to work with scores and regex in a keywords dictionary to get a rudimentary sentiment analysis, with R?

Tags: r, dictionary, string-matching, rating

I would like to optimize the size of a sentiment dictionary by using regular expressions. But I don't know how to match the keywords with the text to be analysed, without losting the rating of each keyword.
I work with R. And I'd like to stay in about a "matching words" solution.

This is what I tried

```
library(stringr)
library(tidytext) # tidy text analysis + unnest_tokens
library(tidyverse) # visualization + tibble

# text to be quoted
Corpus<- c("Radicals in their time, early Impressionists violated the rules of academic painting.",
           "They also painted realistic scenes of modern life, and often painted outdoors.",
           "The public, at first hostile, gradually came to believe that the Impressionists had captured a fresh and original vision.",
           "Even if the art critics and art establishment disapproved of the new style.")

# dictionary : words and quotes lists
WordsList <- c("^academ.+$","^disapprov.*$","^friend.*$","^fresh.*$","^hostil.+$","^modern.*$","^new.*$","^original.*$","^outstand.*$","^radical.*$","^uncorrect.+$","^violat.+$")
QuotesList <- c(1,-2,2,2,-2,2,1,2,3,-3,-1,-3)
Lexicon <- data.frame(words=WordsList, quotes=QuotesList)
Lexicon
#            words   quotes
# 1     ^academ.+$      1
# 2  ^disapprov.*$     -2
# 3     ^friend.*$      2
# 4      ^fresh.*$      2
# 5     ^hostil.+$     -2
# 6     ^modern.*$      2
# 7        ^new.*$      1
# 8   ^original.*$      2
# 9   ^outstand.*$      3
# 10   ^radical.*$     -3
# 11 ^uncorrect.+$     -1
# 12    ^violat.+$     -3

messag <- tibble(docidx = 1:length(Corpus), text = Corpus)
# split into words : 1 row per word per "document"
txt.by.word <- messag %>%
  unnest_tokens(mots, text)

# size order instead of alphabetic order
matching<- paste(Lexicon[order(-nchar(Lexicon$words)),]$words, collapse = '|')
matching
# [1] "^disapprov.*$|^original.*$|^radical.*$|^academ.+$|^hostil.+$|^modern.*$|^violat.+$|^fresh.*$|^new.*$"
# search matchings
test<- str_extract_all(txt.by.word$mots, matching, simplify= T)  # sensible à la casse

# result
test
tst <- as.data.frame(test)
# except empty 
tst[!tst$V1 %in% "",]
# [1] "radicals"    "violated"    "academic"    "modern"      "hostile"     "fresh"       "original"    "disapproved"
# [9] "new"        

# from here I don't know how to get this expected result: by docidx, matching the words and their associated ratings.
# how to extract both the keyword and the sentiment rating ?

# Expected result 
# docidx     text      quote
# 1        radicals     -3
# 1        violated     -3
# 1        academic      1
# 2        modern        2
# 3        hostile      -2
# 3        fresh         2
# 3        original      2
# 4        disapproved  -2
# 4        new           1
```

Comment: probably my question is not clear: I would like to retrieve the sentiment note from the dictionary at the same time as the regex is executed.  str_extract_all inappropriate ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Maël who answered another post from myself, see [an equivalent of the 'match' function that works with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74625178/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-match-function-in-r-that-works-with-regex)
I have found an acceptable solution. Very close to my target. Here the heart of the code to be implemented instead of str_extract_all.

```
'''R
dt.unl <- as.data.table(unlist(sapply(Lexicon$words, grep, Corpus, value = TRUE)), keep.rownames=T)
dt.unl
dt.unl[ , keywords := lapply(.SD, function(x){gsub("[0-9]$", "", x)}), .SDcols=1, by="V1"] 
dt.unl

dt.scor <- merge(dt.unl[,.(V2,keywords)], Lexicon, by.x="keywords", by.y="words")
dt.scor
#          keywords                                                                      V2                                                       quotes
# 1:    \\bacadem.+\\b                                     Radicals in their time, early Impressionists violated the rules of academic painting.      1
# 2: \\bdisapprov.*\\b                                               Even if the art critics and art establishment disapproved of the new style.     -2
# 3:     \\bfresh.*\\b The public, at first hostile, gradually came to believe that the Impressionists had captured a fresh and original vision.      2
# 4:    \\bhostil.+\\b The public, at first hostile, gradually came to believe that the Impressionists had captured a fresh and original vision.     -2
# 5:    \\bmodern.*\\b                                            They also painted realistic scenes of modern life, and often painted outdoors.      2
# 6:       \\bnew.*\\b                                               Even if the art critics and art establishment disapproved of the new style.      1
# 7:  \\boriginal.*\\b The public, at first hostile, gradually came to believe that the Impressionists had captured a fresh and original vision.      2
# 8:    \\bviolat.+\\b                                     Radicals in their time, early Impressionists violated the rules of academic painting.     -3
#
```

'''