# is there an equivalent of the 'match' function in R, that works with regex?

Tags: r, regex, dictionary, match

advantage of 'match', it's returning the matching indices from the lexicon
disadvantage it doesn't accept regex

```r
Corpus<- c('animalada', 'fe', 'fernandez', 'ladrillo')
Lexicon<- c('animal', 'animalada', 'fe', 'fernandez', 'ladr', 'ladrillo')

Index <- match(Corpus, Lexicon)
```

`match` returns the indices of the dictionary

```
Index
# [1] 2 3 4 6

Lexicon[Index]
# [1] "animalada" "fe" "fernandez" "ladrillo"
```

I need to work with a dictionary that includes regex

```r
Lexicon<- c('anima.+$', '.*ez$', '^fe.*$', 'ladr.*$')
```

problem the 'match' function, doesn't work with regex !

Comment: What outpit do you want?

Comment: Thanks for your question onyambu. When a keyword matches a word of the corpus, I want the indice pointing on the Lexicon. In my example : # [1] 2 3 4 6. But 'match' doesn't accept Lexicon with regex as keywords. Initially, the reason why I want this result ? it's to know which keywords did the matching.

Comment: Please note that I asked for the expected results not the readon why. Include your expected results in your wuestion

Comment: I want the indice pointing on the Lexicon. In my example : # [1] 2 3 4 6

Comment: How can you get `2,3,4,6` from the regex Lexicon and the Corpus? Cna you explain how you get 2 for example? It seems your question is incomplete. If you need `2,3,4,6` just do the `match(Corpus, Lexicon)` where `Lexicon` is the first one you gave. There is no way to get a `2,3,4,6` from The `Second Lexicon` you gave. Unless you change the lexicon

Comment: onyambu, unfortunately match doesn't work with regex. thanks for help anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is ill defined. I asked how you get a 2,3,4,6 with the regex Lexicon, but you were unable to explain.

Comment: Onyambu, with the answer from Mael, I get the 1,2,3,4 indices of the regex lexicon Lexicon<- c('anima.+$', '.*ez$', '^fe.*$', 'ladr.*$').  That's the equivalent to the 2,3,4,6 of the initial lexicon. Hope that answers your question. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: The indices freom the solution below are the indices for the Corpus and not the lexicon. Also from the comments below the solution you clearly stated that you want the lexicon indices. But you can not get 2,3,4,6 from lexicon, as your lexicon is of length 4. Also 1,2,3,4 is not equivalent to 2,3,4,6. You have a 6, yet both lexicon and corpus are of length 4. If at all they are equivalent, consider accepting the anser below to close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str_which` + `sapply`. Note that one regex can apply to multiple values, hence the list.

```r
library(stringr)
sapply(Corpus, \(x) str_which(x, Lexicon))

# $animalada
# [1] 1
# 
# $fe
# [1] 3
# 
# $fernandez
# [1] 2 3
# 
# $ladrillo
# [1] 4
```

Comment: thanks Maël for your suggestion. With sapply(Lexicon, grep, Corpus, value = TRUE) we have a beginning of solution. As I need to get the Lexicon row (indice) that matched the corpus. I could use the input regex reminder that is returned by grep.  On the other hand, pmax doesn't make the job, it returns the corpus indice.

Comment: Just remove value = TRUE in that case. You’ll get the indices.

Comment: I don't want the Corpus indice. I want the Lexicon indice in order to get the keyword that has matched. As 'match' does it in my example : # [1] 2 3 4 6 are lexicon indices

Comment: See edit, you can use `str_which`

Comment: @vintdeux How do you want `Lexicon` index yet `Lexicon` contains the `regex`?

Comment: Maël thanks to your help I partially succeed in solving a former post [How to work with scores and regex in a keywords dictionary ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74616143/how-to-work-with-scores-and-regex-in-a-keywords-dictionary-to-get-a-rudimentary/74644069#74644069). I still have another remaining problem that I'm going to explain in a further post and concerning sapply. Many thanks for your efficient help !

Comment: @Maël For my curiosity, what does mean \\(x) in the instruction sapply(Corpus, \\(x) str_which(x, Lexicon))  ?

Comment: It’s a shortcut for function.

Comment: Hello ! Since stringr package release 1.5.0, the above solution no longer works. What would be a workaround ? For information, the release says "stringr functions now consistently implement the tidyverse recycling rules (#372). There are two main changes:  Only vectors of length 1 are recycled. Previously, (e.g.) str_detect(letters, c("x", "y")) worked, but it now errors." 
Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @Maël's answer, if you need the actual values from Lexicon returned, here is a useful idiom (provided the relationship between the two lists is one-to-one:

```
library(stringr)
Lexicon[sapply(Corpus, \(x) str_which(x, Lexicon))]
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, sorry for the late comment.